# Add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to header on fetch method by chrome terminal

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I am trying to test CORS on my simple web service.

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

var corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://example.com',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200 
}

app.get('/products/:id', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
    res.json({ msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for only example.com.' })
})

app.listen(80, function () {
    console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

In the chrome terminal by using fetch command I want to call my service :

```
fetch("http://localhost/products/1", {   credentials: 'include', headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://example.com'
    },}).then(req => req.text()).then(console.log)
```

but I got error:

```
search:1 Access to fetch at 'http://localhost/products/1' from origin 'https://www.google.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
VM331:1 GET http://localhost/products/1 net::ERR_FAILED
```

I added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to my request but not works!

Comment: Specify the port? Which ports is your application runnning on? `http://localhost:3000/products`

Comment: @Dharmaraj I have posted the answer, he added example.com in origin, which won't work

Comment: run on port 80 `app.listen(80,` @Dharmaraj

Comment: Try `fetch("http://localhost:80/products/1")`. Also as @SachinAnanthakumar mentioned, which domain do you have set in `cors()` middleware? If you just share some imaginary config then it'll be hard to resolve it.

Comment: This is complete code with try https://pasteboard.co/Kj1shmS.png @Dharmaraj

Comment: @CyrustheGreat Check my answer I have covered all possible cases, in your case try setting origin like this `origin: "*"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the different cases I have mentioned below, Your Question falls under CASE 1, If in case you are trying to make a request from a website in local or in production, you can refer other cases.

**CASE 1**

If you are planning only to make requests from tabs, the it is best to set origin property inside corsOption to **"*"** like this.

**origin: "*"**

**CASE 2**

If you want to send request to the server from an application running on your local host then add "http://localhost:(port of Front end app)" to the origin property

**origin: "http://localhost:<website_port>"**

**CASE 3**

If your front end app is deployed somewhere then the domain of that website should be added to the origin property like this

**origin: "www.mywebsite.com"**

**CASE 4**

Mutiple websites needs to consume the API, then add the an array of domains in the origin property like this

**origin: ['domain1', 'domain2', ...]**

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

var corsOptions = {
   origin: 'http://localhost:<the port>', //? can be a array of domains too
   optionsSuccessStatus: 200 
}

app.get('/products/:id', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({ msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for only example.com.' })
})

app.listen(80, function () {
   console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Comment: I change to `origin: 'http://localhost:80',` but I still got error: https://pasteboard.co/Kj1p6yE.png @SachinAnanthakumar

Comment: which port is your frontend application running in?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I think then he needs to set https://google.com as origin,

Comment: Depends on which domain is open in that browser tab.

Comment: @Dharmaraj If his only goal is to make request from terminal then he needs to make origin to * or remove corsOption.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to whitelist localhost only on development then you can try the following:

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'DEVELOPMENT' ? true : /https:.*?\.?domain\.com/,
}
```

In production it'll allow your domain and sub-domains only.

The domain you specify in `corsOptions` will be allowed to make requests to your server. In your case you are using browser's terminal and hence the domain you are on will be taken as origin. Since you have Google open, you must set that in your `corOptions`:

```
const corsOptions = {
   origin: 'https://google.com',
   optionsSuccessStatus: 200 
}
```

Also specify the port your express app is running on:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost/products/1' from origin 'https://www.google.com' has been blocked by CORS policy
```

The URL should be `http://localhost:80/products/1` in this case.

If you'll be using browser terminal for testing then I'd recommend setting the origin to true which will allow requests from any origin:

```
const corsOption = {
  origin: true
}
```

If you don't have a web app and just need to test the API, consider using API clients like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) or [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest). You can read more about CORS configuration in the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html).